How do you display an alphabetical caller name of a customer like 'Joe' for an incoming call when forwarding the call to an agent/staff cellphone?
We have developed a telephony CRM solution for our customers, many of whom are small businesses. I will refer to the businesses as our customers and the businesses customers as clients for the remainder of this post. We have a mobile app that our customers use.
Here is a quick outline of our soultion.

The incoming calls from our business customers are offloaded to a web hook into our application on the cloud, and the code then forwards each of the calls to a staff/agent of that business that we have stored in our repository.

We also know the incoming callers name, aka client of the business, which is also stored in our repository.

We would like to display the name of the client to the staff/agent to whom the call is being  forwarded.

We are unable to display this name and I believe the issue we are having, is that Twilio uses its technology to forward the call and the last mile of the call is going through a cellphone carrier in the U.S. I think the carriers ignore the caller name even if we try to set it because of CNAM and hence the issue.


My question is, whether this can even be done the way we have implemented our solution ?
The documentation suggests that a number in the E+ format is o.k but a name is usually prevented unless the name is registered in the CNAM and it is still is not guaranteed to be displayed by all carriers. I believe the carriers control the last leg because if they allow it, then spoofing is easy for scamsters.
If this is not possible, then how do some of the other products like JustCall do it as I believe they are also on the Twilio Stack.
Is this possible if we use Twilio voice SDK and make the call directly to our mobile app which is used by the staff/agent ?
Thank You
We have tried using the Dial verb and experimented with CallerId.
